# ordering ggplot facets dynamically

Tags: r, ggplot2

What are recommended ways to order facets dynamically from left to right for:

(1) highest to lowest most recent price (so, b>a>c facets left to right) and

(2) highest to lowest average price (c>b>a)?

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

start_date <- ymd("2019-04-01")
end_date <- ymd("2019-04-06")

date <- rep(seq(start_date, end_date, by = "days"),3)
price <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,7,6,5,4,3)
class <- c(rep("a",6), rep("b",6), rep("c",6) )
df <- data.frame(date, price, class)

ggplot(df, aes(date, price)) + facet_wrap(~class) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to get the facets to show up in that order? Make the faceting variable a factor and set the levels in the order you'd like. In your example:

```
 df$class <- factor(df$class, levels = c("b", "a", "c"))
 ggplot(df, aes(date, price)) + facet_wrap(~class) + geom_line()
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I am, but in a case without example data with many more classes in an unknown order, I'd like the plot to inform the order to me.  so maybe something along the lines of guess `levels = desc(new_stat_column))`?

Comment: @doconnor Yes, just pass something that is ordered the way you want to `levels`.